# how to show $ A$ open?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the maximum modulus principle by showing the set $A$ is open and colse

let $U$ be a domain in $\Bbb C$ and $f:U→C$ analytic in $U$. If there exists $z_0 \in\Bbb U$ such that $|f(z)|≤|f(z_0 )|$ for all $z\in U$

and let $A=${$z\in U| f(z)=f(z_0 )$} how to show $A$ is open without using maximum modulus principle?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the maximum modulus principle? Because it's too easy? How about if you write down the proof of the maximum modulus principle, and use that as your solution?

Comment: @Arthur i'm trying to prove maximum modulus principle by showing $A$ is open and closed, but I can't find a way to prove $A$ is open

Comment: Trying to prove the maximum modulus principle would be a valid reason for not using the maximum modulus principle. Why didn't you say so in your original post?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. You may use the Mean Value Theorem:

Assume that ${B}(z_0,r)\subset U$. Then, 
$$
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+s\mathrm{e}^{it})\,dt
$$
for every $s\in (0,r)$, and hence
$$
|\,f(z_0)|\le\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|\,f(z_0+s\mathrm{e}^{it})|\,dt\le |\,f(z_0)|.
$$
The last inequality is a consequence of the assumption that $|\,f(z_0)|$ is maximum. Hence, 
$$
|\,f(z)|=|\,f(z_0)|, \quad \text{for all $z\in B(z_0,r)$},
$$
and thus 
$$
f(z)=f(z_0), \quad \text{for all $z\in B(z_0,r)$},
$$